# Wemos D1 not able to run code

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I bought this board [image]

[image]

As far as I can tell I installed the drivers and libraries properly(I can see the board in the usb devices and upload the code), but every time I try to run a program, I get this result in the serial monitor[image] and the board doesnt light up any led. I also tried to just print an hello world, but i get the same result.

My configs are :
[image]

And a example is:
[image]

I hope you can help me out, thank you!

Comment: looks like it's working (at least not fried) if you have the wdt dump in the serial monitor. try an external LED, the assignments on those "wannabe uno" can be wacky.

Comment: I going to try that, but shouldn't in the case of the "hello world" the wacky assignments be irrelevant? Shouldn't the serial monitor still print "hello world" instead of the rubbish ?

Comment: wacky assignments are irrelevant if you use gpio numbers instead of constants that are defined in boards.txt, which on less than popular boards are subject to mistakes, revision diffs, bad ebay sellers, etc. if you set the pin mode of gpio1 or never call serial.begin, only the rubbish should print legibly. post the hello world code that's not working and we can take a look, hard to speculate without code

Comment: Thank you for the help, I ended up asking for a new one from the seller. Now everything works just fine.The problem was that the board was faulty one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the LED not blinking is because many of the ESP12 boards use GPIO 2 rather than GPIO 1 for the built in LED.
See this [issue](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2192) for more details.

Try adding this to the beginning of the sketch:

```
#define LED_BUILTIN 2
```

or just use `2` in place of `LED_BUILTIN`

which will re-define LED_BUILTIN to use gpio 2 rather than gpio 1

As for the serial monitor, I have not directly used the Arduino IDE in a while,  but you are not printing anything to the serial port anyway.

Here is an updated version of the sketch that should blink the led and print some messages to the monitor.  (set the baud rate of the serial port to 115200 in the IDE)

```
#define LED_BUILTIN 2  

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  Serial.println("turning ON LED");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
                                    // but actually the LED is on; this is because 
                                    // it is acive low on the ESP-01)
  delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
  Serial.println("turning OFF LED");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  delay(2000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. 

It seems to be something else, I used your code and I got exactly the same result. No led turn on and just the same rubbish string. It seems to completely ignore the code, I was at least expecting to see the string repeating periodically, but no. Any other ideia what it might be?

Comment: I've not seen GPIO2 used for LED, only TX (GPIO1) and GPIO16. If you use GPIO1, you can't use hardware serial.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was a faulty board. I requested a new one from the seller, and the one worked just fine with the code that I provided in the question.